# Enable all rules with .NET analyzers in .NET standard projects

Tags: c#

I am moving my project to the new .NET Analyzers using Rosyln, previously I was using the nuget package.
I'm trying to do the process described here:
[Migrate from FxCop analyzers to .NET analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/migrate-from-fxcop-analyzers-to-net-analyzers?view=vs-2019)

Now my csproj looks like:

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
    <AnalysisMode>AllEnabledByDefault</AnalysisMode>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

If `TargetFramework` is `net5.0`, all rules are return an error, but I cannot make it work when it's set to `netstandard2.0`.
I cannot move to `net5.0` because this dll is referenced by a `.NET 4.8` project.

Comment: What isn't working in the netstandard2.0 project? Are you seeing the warnings but they're not being turned into errors? Or are you not seeing the warnings at all?

Comment: Add `<AnalysisLevel>5</AnalysisLevel>` to use the stricter baseline: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/automatically-find-latent-bugs-in-your-code-with-net-5/

Comment: @MartinCostello Thanks a lot, adding `<AnalysisLevel>5</AnalysisLevel>` solved the issue.

Comment: @PDufrene How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could Accept it as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you add `<AnalysisLevel>5</AnalysisLevel>` to your project file, you can instruct projects which do not target .NET 5.0 to use the same default rules as a project targeting `net5.0` would do by default.

You can find more information about this [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/automatically-find-latent-bugs-in-your-code-with-net-5/).

Answer (score 0):

Since moving to .Net 5 is not an option (where the analyzer is enabled automatically), I would suggest using the nuget package[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/) that perform the analysis.